# EF Code first optional to optional with a single FK column

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am trying to have an optional-to-optional relationship. I think I'm pretty close, but for some reason, Entity Framework fails to use the predefined FK property on my entity.

```
public class Foo
{
    public Guid? BarId { get; set; }
    public virtual Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public virtual Foo Foo { get; set; }
}
```

This is exactly what I want to see in the database. Foo has an FK column, but Bar does not have an FK to Foo.

And the Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<Foo>()
    .HasOptional(f => f.Bar)
    .WithOptionalDependent(b => b.Foo);
```

However, when I generate the database, EF has set the `FooId` property as a simple scalar property, and has created its own `Foo_Id` that it uses for the FK.

Everything else is as I expect it, the `Bar` table has no FK field to `Foo`.

Looking online, I found a suggestion to do the following:

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<Foo>()
    .HasOptional(f => f.Bar)
    .WithOptionalDependent(b => b.Foo)
    .Map(d => d.MapKey("BarId"));
```

However, this doesn't work unless I remove the `BarId` from my `Foo` class, and I don't want to do that. I specifically want to keep the `BarId` so I can use it to create/destroy the relationship when I need to.

**How can I get EF to use the FK property that I've created, instead of generating an extra column and using that?**

*Sidenote: I don't want to use data annotations. The entire solution is built around separating the entities (domain project) from the data provider (database EF project). We exclusively use Fluent API to set it all up.*

---

For completeness' sake, the intention is that `Bar` can have multiple of these relationships:

```
public class ADifferentFoo
{
    public Guid? BarId { get; set; }
    public virtual Bar Bar { get; set; }
}
```

This is why I don't want to have FKs in Bar: you'd end up with a column for each, and we know that a Bar will only every have one relationship.

---

Maybe a concrete example helps:

`Foo` = `Person`
`Bar` = `Picture`
`ADifferentFoo` = `Car`

A Person can optionally have a Picture. A Car can optionally have a Picture.

A picture always belongs to either a Car **XOR** a Person, never both.
But as far as I care, this doesn't need to be explicitly enforced on the databse level. The business logic can handle that.

Similarly, I don't care about Pictures without any Car or Person - I don't need them, but it's not a problem if the data model allows them to exist. The business logic will already cover that gap as well.

Comment: "A picture always belongs to either a Car XOR a Person, never both."  How do you propose to enforce that without FK columns on Picture?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft It shouldn't really be enforced. The Person and Car business logic handlers will create their own pictures. My intention was more to stress that there will never be a use case for having both FKs, rather than explicitly having to enforce it. Maybe I should rephrase it. (Tangentially, out of curiosity, how do you propose to enforce it _with_ FKs in the Picture table?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just:

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public int PictureId { get; set; }
    public virtual Picture Picture { get; set; }

}
public class Car
{
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public int PictureId { get; set; }
    public virtual Picture Picture { get; set; }
}

public class Picture
{
    public int PictureId { get; set; }
}
```

?

And

> how do you propose to enforce it with FKs in the Picture table?

You could use a CHECK CONSTRAINT

That is all assuming EF 6, and those are one-to-many relationships.

For a 1-1 the FK has to be a key, and EF 6 doesn't support multiple keys.

EF Core has a first-class notion of Alternate Keys, and not only can you use an FK that points to an Alternate Key, you can use an FK that *is* an Alternate Key to implement a 1-to-1 relationship.  EG

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Linq;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace efCoreTest
{

    public class Person
    {
        public int PersonID { get; set; }
        public int? PictureId { get; set; }
        public virtual Picture Picture { get; set; }

    }
    public class Car
    {
        public int CarId { get; set; }
        public int? PictureId { get; set; }
        public virtual Picture Picture { get; set; }
    }

    public class Picture
    {
        public int PictureId { get; set; }
        public virtual Car Car { get; set; }

        public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    }


    public partial class Db : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Picture> Pictures { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Car>().HasAlternateKey(c => c.PictureId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().HasAlternateKey(c => c.PictureId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Car>().HasOne(c => c.Picture).WithOne(p => p.Car);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().HasOne(c => c.Picture).WithOne(p => p.Person);
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=localhost;database=efcore2test;integrated security=true");
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var db = new Db())
            {


                db.Database.EnsureDeleted();
                db.Database.EnsureCreated();

                var c = new Car();
                var p = new Person();

                var pic = new Picture();
                pic.Car = c;
                pic.Person = p;

                db.Add(c);
                db.Add(p);
                db.Add(pic);

                db.SaveChanges();


            }

            Console.WriteLine("Hit any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this model does permit a Car and a Person to share a single Picture.

Comment: So I basically can't have a nav prop in the Picture class? This feels weird, EF is perfectly capable of giving me two-way nav props for a one to many, yet it can't do that for one-to-ones, which are structurally (database-wise) exactly the same. Somehow doesn't EF identify (nor give me an option to specify) an existing FK constraint, even though it does do that for the one to manys... If there is no other answer I'll accept this, but I'm holding out for an answer that fixes the issue rather than hides it from sight.